# Need help in showing that the standard action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}$ is proper.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

I have to show that the action 
$$
\lambda\cdot z:= \lambda z,
$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$, and $z\in \mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}$ is proper, i.e.
the map
$$
\mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{C}^n-\{0\} \to (\mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}) \times (\mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}), (\lambda,z)\mapsto (\lambda z,z)
$$
is proper.

I tried showing that the map is open, which is sufficient as it is injective. I also tried to show that the preimage of a closed, bounded set is closed and bounded, but I couldn't come up with a proof.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: A Lie group action on a manifold is proper if and only if for each sequence of pairs $(\lambda_i,z_i)$ such that $(z_i)$ converges and $\lambda_iz_i$ converges, a subsequence of $(\lambda_i)$ converges. (This is Proposition 21.5 in my _Intro to Smooth Manifolds_, 2nd ed.)

Comment: BTW, one thing you wrote above is not correct -- an injective open continuous map need not be proper. A counterexample is the inclusion $(0,1)\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: You can write this action as a product action of $S^1$ om the sphere $S^{2n-1}$ and $R^+$ on itself. Both are obviously proper. And you immediately see that the quotient is the same as the quotient of $S^{2n-1}$ by $S^1$, a projective space.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you very much, the approach using sequences worked out great! I'm sorry for the rather late response.

Comment: You're welcome!